# Error while installing unity-tweak-tool on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, apt, dpkg, unity-tweak-tool

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

results in

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  account-plugin-windows-live libupstart1 linux-headers-3.16.0-30
  linux-headers-3.16.0-30-generic linux-image-3.16.0-30-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-30-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  unity-tweak-tool
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/333 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,610 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package unity-tweak-tool.
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 reading files list for package 'texlive-fonts-recommended': Input/output error
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

before doing this I used this command.

```
sudo -E apt-add-repository ppa:izx/askubuntu -y
```

`sudo apt-get update` results in this error

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/izx/askubuntu/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Edit1: I tried to install other packages but that dpkg error keeps showing up.

Comment: The `ppa:izx/askubuntu` has no packages for 14.04 (trusty). You should remove it (using `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:izx/askubuntu` or better using `sudo ppa-purge ppa:izx/askubuntu`, but you must have ppa-purge installed for the second variant).

Comment: Then run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`, if it still reports not upgraded or held back packages, also run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. Then report back what happened.

Answer (score -1):

This is reiterating what the first two replies said,  but I've added a few extra steps along with why you're  doing them.

First run

```
 uname - r
```

to find what kernel version you're using.  As the update is reporting that you have an older kernel installed that is no longer required.

The first two listed are programs you no longer need - these can be safely removed, they'll be reinstalled later if they are in fact needed.

Let me repeat,  IF, AND ONLY IF,  your computer is giving you no problems run 'sudo apt-get autoremove'

The PPA error is saying that either you mistyped the address for the PPA or that the PPA no longer exists. As previously reported,  its nit for your version,  remive it.

This error can be ignored for the moment, more on this later.

In other words perform the following steps:

```
uname - r
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get install --fix-missing
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

My original post had a few more steps until I saw that the PPA is not for Trusty.

Comment: How does this address the PPA not found error??? It does not, you say "This error can be ignored for the moment" but that is the very question, it can't be ignored, that is the issue,  this answer is terrible, you talk about multiple things that have nothing to do with the question and offer no solution to the error -1